# Search error using PHP and AJAX need opinion

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem in my code. When I try to make search in my application which error is

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method `category::SearchOnCategorya()` in C:\xampp\htdocs\newspaper\cpannel\ajaxcat.php:210 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\newspaper\cpannel\ajaxcat.php on line 210

This is my class category code

```
public static function SearchOnCategorya($data)
{
    global $dbh;
    $sql=$dbh->prepare("select * from category where name like '%$data%'");

    if($sql->execute()){
         $allcategories = $sql->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         return $allcategories;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

This is the jQuery and ajax code

```
$(function (){
      $("#catserch").on("keyup",function (){
          var serach=$(this).val();

          var action="searchcategory";
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajaxcat.php",
                method: "post",
                data: {action: action, serach:serach},
                beforeSend: function () {

                    $(".img-ad").fadeIn();

                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $(".serchresult").html(data);
                    $(".img-ad").fadeOut();
                },
                error: function () {
                    $(".serchresult").html("error");
                    $(".img-ad").fadeOut();

                }
            })
      })
  })
```

This is my PHP code:

```
 case'searchcategory':
      echo  $data=$_POST['serach'];

       echo '<table  class="table table-striped  table-bordered table-hover">
                   <thead>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>manager</th>
                    </thead>
        <tbody>';
       $allcattt= category::SearchOnCategorya($data);
       print_r($allcattt);
       if(is_array($allcattt)&& count($allcattt)>0){
           foreach ($allcattt as $category):
               echo'

                    <td> '.$category['id'].'</td>
                        <td> '.$category['name'].'</td>
                            <td> '.editor::retriveeditornamebyid($category['id_manager']).'</td>

                    </tbody>


               </table>';
           endforeach;
       }else{

       }
        break;
```

This is class category:

```
<?php

require_once '../config.php';

class category {

    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $id_manager;

    public function __construct($name, $id_manager, $id = "") {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->id_manager = $id_manager;
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function addcategory() {
        global $dbh;
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("insert into category (name,id_manager)values('$this->name','$this->id_manager')");
        if ($sql->execute()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public static function retrieveAllCategories() {
        global $dbh;
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("select * from category order by id desc limit 0,10");
        if ($sql->execute()) {
            $allcategories = $sql->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $allcategories;
        } else {
            return false;
            ;
        }
    }

    public static function deletecategorybyid($id) {
        global $dbh;
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("delete from category where id='$id'");
        if ($sql->execute()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public static function retrivecategorybyid($id) {
        global $dbh;
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("select * from category where id= '$id'");
        if ($sql->execute()) {
            $category = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $category;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function updatecategorybyid() {
        global $dbh;
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("update category set name='$this->name',id_manager='$this->id_manager' where id='$this->id'");
        if ($sql->execute()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public static function RetriveTotalCategoryCount() {
        global $dbh;
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("select id from category");
        if ($sql->execute()) {
            return $sql->rowcount();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static function RetriveLatestInsertCategoryId() {

        global $dbh;

        $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM category ORDER BY id DESC limit 1");

        if ($sql->execute()) {
            $all = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $all['id'];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static function RetriveCategoryNameBYID($id) {
        global $dbh;
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name FROM category where id ='$id'");
        if ($sql->execute()) {
            // $name=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $name = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $name['name'];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static function xy() {
        global $dbh;
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM category ");
        if ($sql->execute()) {
            return $dbh->lastInsertId();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static function retrieveAllCategoriesxx() {
        global $dbh;
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("select * from category ");
        if ($sql->execute()) {
            $allcategories = $sql->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $allcategories;
        } else {
            return false;
            ;
        }
    }

    public static function RETRIVEnumberOFCATEGORIESMANGEDBYidmanager($id_manager) {
        global $dbh;
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("select id from category where id_manager='$id_manager'");
        if ($sql->execute()) {
            return $sql->rowcount();
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public static function RetriveAllCategoriesidMangedbyIDManager($id_manager) {

        global $dbh;

        $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM category WHERE id_manager='$id_manager'");

        if ($sql->execute()) {

            $allCategories = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if (is_array($allCategories) && count($allCategories) > 0) {
                $allCategoriesId = null;


                foreach ($allCategories as $category):
                    $allCategoriesId[] = $category['id'];
                endforeach;
                return $allCategoriesId;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static function Rtrivecategorymangertbycategoryid($id)
    {
         global $dbh;

        $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id_manager FROM category WHERE id='$id'");


        if($sql->execute()){

            $category =  $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(is_array($category)){
                return $category['id_manager'];
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static function SearchOnCategory($data)
    {
        global $dbh;
        $sql=$dbh->prepare("select * from category where name like '%$data%'");

        if($sql->execute()){
             $allcategories = $sql->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
             return $allcategories;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: $allcattt= category::SearchOnCategorya($data); 
Where is "category" defined? Is it ment to be $category?

Comment: @PascalClaes shouldn't need to define a variable since it's a static function.

Comment: Did you include the category class file in your search PHP script? Does the class category start with a capital (e.g. Category:: instead of category::)?

Comment: yes category class included@Pascal Claes,@ ADyson

Comment: if the class itself wouldn't be found the error msg would be `Class 'category' not found` - so I doubt you showed the right class here. Please show the class category (it's definition, not _all_ of the methods..).

Comment: @ADyson no smal letter and this is my class

Comment: @jeff i receved data when i echo $data=$_Post['search]

Comment: _"this is my class"_ - no, the code shown isn't a class yet. It's only a method that should live inside the class `category`. I wanna know where and how it lives there.

Comment: @AhmedGaber yes, I realized, you have that typo everywhere, so it'll work.

Comment: @jeff how  can i post my class category now  i tried to write it in  comment but it about 460 line

Comment: edit the question. remove other methods (with `//...` as replacement), that aren't involved.

Comment: @Jeff  the output must be a table but i founf the the error above

Comment: @jeff done you can check it now

Comment: @Pascal Claes check now i uploade class category

Comment: "public static function SearchOnCategorya($data)"...this is not shown within your category class example above. So based on that, this is the reason for your error. "SearchOnCategory($data)" is, though...

Comment: Well, the method is called `SearchOnCategory`. no `a` after that.

Comment: It's probably worth some time and effort to check your spelling everywhere to avoid these kind of mistakes.

Comment: you really should keep a very close eye on how you name functions, vars, etc. You have `search, serach`, you have `retrieve, retrive, rtrive`, you have `managed, manged`,...

Comment: @ Pascal Claes,@ ADyson,@Jeff   the same error found

Comment: And it's the simplest error you can make. A Typo. For that you've kept a bunch of coders busy for 30 minutes.

Comment: any one can help me

Comment: what do you mean? We've given you the answer - you made a typing error

Comment: @ADyson ichange the name of function but still have the same error

Comment: go through __all__ your function names and how you call them. Correct _all_ the spelling mistakes (and there are a lot). This error you've got is the symtom of those spelling errors.

Comment: and get a consistant namingConvention throughout your project.

Answer (score 0):

In your class, you have:

```
public static function SearchOnCategory($data)
```

In your call, you have:

```
SearchOnCategorya
```

Notice the extra letter `a` in your call? You are spelling the function incorrectly.